# Hive on Talend 5.6.1 using CDH 5.2: External table on Gzip compressed file, table gives garbage values

Tags: hadoop, hive, gzip, talend, cloudera-cdh

[Talend file generation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHQbO.png)

Versions: 
Talend 5.6.1
CDH 5.2

**Issue Description:**
I am creating a Gzip compressed file, (using tRowGenerator) and storing it directly into HDFS. Then creating an HIVE EXTERNAL table on this file (STORAGE AS TEXTFILE). 
When i am issuing SELECT * FROM this external table (on HUE), i am getting garbage values.

Alternative steps taken:
1) Created the same file in HDFS.
2) Moved it to LOCAL machine.
3) Gzip the file using "gzip ".
4) Transfered this file to HDFS again.
5) Created the same HIVE EXTERNAL TABLE on this file.

SELECT * FROM, gives correct value.

Query:
Can any one guide me, if i am doing something wrong. Or this is a known bug.

Comment: Does Talend generate the compressed files with the expected `.gz` extension? Otherwise Hive cannot guess that they are compressed...

Comment: Or maybe you have run into a subtle compatibility gap between different implementations of GZip, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614126/hive-gzip-file-decompression

Comment: The file generated by Talend is not with .gz extention, that can be causing issue. I will try renaming the file with this extention while storing itself and will post the results.

Comment: renaming the file with extension .gz in this scenario, is working perfectly fine. Thanks for the solution provided, Samson.